# Hilbert schemes and moduli of ideal sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. The Hilbert scheme on $X$ parametrizes quotients $\mathcal{O}_X \to E$ with fixed Hilbert polynomial. Let us fix the Hilbert polynomial to lead to subschemes of codimension at least $2$. Then we can also look at the moduli space parametrizing semistable rank $1$ sheaves with corresponding Hilbert polynomial and trivial determinant, i.e. ideal sheaves.

Whenever we have a family of quotients, we can take the kernel to get a family of ideal sheaves. That should induce a bijective morphism. However, it seems unclear to me how to get an inverse morphisms.

Under what kind of hypotheses are these two moduli spaces the same? I am in particular interested in the case of Hilbert schemes of curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

**Edit:** Since I never wrote it down and it came up in the comments, let me write down what the functors are I am exactly talking about.

The Hilbert scheme represents the functor that maps $S$ to quotients $\mathcal{O}_{X \times S} \to E$ that are flat over the base $S$.

The moduli of semistable sheaves represents the functor that maps $S$ to flat families $E \in \operatorname{Coh}(X \times S)$ of semistable sheaves modulo tensoring with line bundles pulled back from $S$.

We then look at the corresponding connected components coming from fixing the Hilbert polynomial and ask whether they are the same.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that $$\mathscr{I}_Z^{\vee\vee}\simeq \mathscr{O}_X,$$ because the left-hand side is reflexive and isomorphic to $\mathscr{O}_X$ away from $Z$, which has codimension at least $2$ by assumption.  In other words, the abstract sheaf $\mathscr{I}_Z$ is *canonically* embedded in $\mathscr{O}_X$ via the double-dual map $$\mathscr{I}_Z\to \mathscr{I}_Z^{\vee\vee}\simeq \mathscr{O}_X.$$

So the inverse map you are looking for is induced by $$\mathscr{I}_Z\mapsto (\mathscr{O}_X\simeq\mathscr{I}_Z^{\vee\vee}\to \text{coker}(\mathscr{I}_Z\to \mathscr{I}_Z^{\vee\vee})\simeq \mathscr{O}_Z).$$

I suppose I used that $X$ is smooth in the identification $$\mathscr{I}_Z^{\vee\vee}\simeq \mathscr{O}_X,$$ but you can probably relax this a bit. (I'm a little worried about making this work in families, which is, strictly speaking, necessary; so this answer is not quite complete.)

Comment: Does semi-stability of the ideal sheaf give no conditions on the corresponding subscheme?

Comment: @MattiaTalpo: Aren't rank one torsion-free sheaves (e.g. ideal sheaves) always semi-stable? Any torsion-free subsheaf is rank one, and must have lower degree, right?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: "I'm a little worried about making this work in families, which is, strictly speaking, necessary; so this answer is not quite complete."  Please see EGA III_2, Corollaire 7.7.8.2, p. 70: $Y$ is the moduli space of sheaves, $X$ is the product of $Y$ and your fixed variety, $\mathcal{F}$ is the structure sheaf of $X$, and $\mathcal{G}$ is the universal ideal sheaf.  Proj of the symmetric algebra of $\mathcal{N}$ is the scheme which naturally maps to the Hilbert scheme.  It remains to prove that $\mathcal{N}$ is invertible.  This can be checked on closed, affine, Artin subschemes of $Y$.

Comment: This answer is the explanation why the map is a bijection, but it seems to me the critical part is why it works in families. Jason's answer seems promising. I will try to fully understand it.

Comment: By the way, if $X$ is a proper Deligne-Mumford stack (rather than a scheme), then existence of $\mathcal{N}$ is generalized via the following article: M. Lieblich, "Remarks on the stack of coherent algebras", Int. Math. Res. Not. 2006, Art. ID 75273.  If $X$ is a proper Artin stack whose diagonal is finite, this follows from the following article: Olsson, M.
"Hom-stacks and restriction of scalars." Duke Math. J. 134 (2006), no. 1, 139–164.

Comment: I understand how to apply the Corollary from EGA. So we get a morphism $\mathcal{G} \to p_Y^* \mathcal{N}$ which corresponds to the identity of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O_Y}}(\mathcal{N}, \mathcal{N})$.

My first question is why this map is injective? This seems to be necessary to get the correct Hilbert polynomial when taking the quotient.

Comment: I am also confused about your last sentence about checking that $\mathcal{N}$ is invertible on closed affine artin subschemes. Why is that enough and how do you actually check it? I was trying to prove that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O_Y}}(\mathcal{N}, \mathcal{O_Z}) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O_X}}(\mathcal{G}, p_Y^* \mathcal{O_Z})$ has dimension equal to the length of the closed affine artin subscheme $Z$, but failed when $Z$ is not just a reduced point. Is this even going in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Since formation of $\mathcal{N}$ is compatible with arbitrary base change, by Daniel's argument the base change of $\mathcal{N}$ from $Y$ to each closed point $y$ of $Y$ is a rank $1$ locally free sheaf. Also, by construction $\mathcal{N}$ is coherent.  Thus, by Nakayama's Lemma, Zariski locally $\mathcal{N}$ is a quotient of the structure sheaf of $Y$.  If the kernel of this quotient is not zero, then Krull's Intersection Theorem implies the same after base change to $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}/\mathfrak{m}_{Y,y}^N$, which is Artinian.

Comment: Jason's argument shows that $\mathscr{N}$ is a line bundle on $X\times S$ pulled back from the base $S$; to conclude that it is in fact trivial (and hence $\mathscr{N}^{\vee}$ is trivial, which is what we want) use that $\mathscr{N}^\vee\simeq \det(\mathscr{I}_Z)$ b/c it is so away from $Z$ (and its formation commutes w/ base change) and is locally free; but your condition is that $\det(\mathscr{I}_Z)$ is trivial.

Comment: I very much doubt you can show that $\mathcal{N}$ is trivial. The most you can do is what Jason says that it is a pullback of a line bundle from $S$. The reason is that the universal family is in fact only well defined up to tensoring with line bundles coming from $S$. But that is enough anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminSchmidt: I think I disagree,  but maybe you can tell me where I'm going wrong--can't you pin down the universal family by requiring that its determinant be globally trivial?

Comment: I see. I think you can do that. In general, when you have a moduli space of Gieseker semistable sheaves you can only define the functor up to tensoring with line bundles from the base? However, you are probably right that this can be fixed in the case of ideal sheaves. At the end of the day, it is not necessary.

Comment: I think it actually is necessary--you want a map from a moduli space of sheaves to a hilbert scheme.  So you need a way of going from a family of sheaves to a family of schemes, in this case by taking the cokernel of the map I produce and arguing that it is the structure sheaf of a subscheme.  Unless you pin down the family as I suggest, it simply won't be; rather it'll be a line bundle on a subscheme...

Comment: This is a matter of what the functors exactly are and I guess I never wrote that down. Let me add it to the original post. I explicitly am interested in the situation where we don't fix it.